# Input field not being updated from controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in learning phase of Angularjs and am stuck in a problem for last two days. I have seen lots of answer but don't know how to adapt those solutions in my case. What I want to do is update the input field via buttons using angularjs.

```
// html
<body ng-controller="Controller">

    <input type="number" ng-model="data" update-view>
            <br>
    <label for="data">{{data}}</label>
    <button name="btn1"  ng-click='updateInput(1)'>1</button>

</body>

  // js
 var app = angular.module('calculator',[]);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.data = 0;
    var val = '';
    $scope.updateInput = function(param) {

        val += String(param);
        $scope.data = val;
        // val = param;
        // $scope.data = val;       
    }

});
```

The expressions gets evaluated but the input field is not updating. I have seen other updating views with `$setViewValue` and `$render` but I don't know how to use them here.

```
app.directive('updateView', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.bind('change', function () {
                // console.log(ngModel);
                scope.$apply(setAnotherValue);
            });
            function setAnotherValue() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.data);
                ngModel.$render();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was noting that without converting the parameter into string, the input field would update with the changed model but as soon as I would change it into String, it would not update the input field. Also there was error thrown in console. So I just, on hit and trial basis, converted it back to `int` by changing only one piece of line `$scope.data = val;` into `$scope.data = parseInt(val, 10);` and hurrrayyy the input field is all updating just like I wanted. And as @cither suggested, I don't need to directive for this. Following is my working code

```
var app = angular.module('calculator',[]);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $timeout){
        $scope.data = 0;
        var val = '';
        $scope.updateInput = function(param) {

            val += String(param);
            $scope.data = parseInt(val, 10);       
        }

    });
```

Comment: I see. This will also work, then. `$scope.data = $scope.data * 10 + param`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a directive for updating. 
You seem to be setting a string value to `$scope.data`, which throws an error, because the input type is `number`.

```js
angular.module('calculator', [])
.controller('Controller', function($scope){
  $scope.data = 0;
  var val = '';
  $scope.updateInput = function(n){
    val = n;
    $scope.data = val;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="calculator" ng-controller="Controller">
  <input type="number" ng-model="data">
  <button ng-click="updateInput(1)">1</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not what i want. I want to keep pressing the button and the result should be displayed in text field like 1111 for pressing the button 4 times.